# GoogleApiClient must not be null [Awareness API]

Tags: android, dependency-injection, rx-java, google-api-client, dagger-2

I'm trying to find out why the Google Play Services is crashing with a nullpointerexception after the application is coming back from a background state such as device sleep or toggle other program. Sometimes Google Play Services gives the crash popup on application start. So I assume the problem lies somewhere on the path to the service since there is where the threading occurs with rxjava.

```
Note: I Inject GoogleApiClient in both MainActivity (field injection) and in GoogleApiService (constructor injection).
```

GoogleApiClient is injected as a @Singleton. I've been trying to trace why this is happening for hours now without progress, any help appreciated.

**The Application continues to work without any issues, the "Google Play Services popup" is annoying though**, I see one call to getuserLocAndWeather() return lost connection to google play services, but it immediatly returns a valid result in the next call.

The actual object reference in MainActivity and GoogleApiService is never null, the reference is always the same, like com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqd@a768e13 and always connected when the call is made.

Trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: lowpool[3]
Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 12828
java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null
     at ilk.a(:com.google.android.gms:73)
     at hys.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:115)
     at pof.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:86)
     at ppz.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:35)
     at ppx.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:179)
     at ppp.a(:com.google.android.gms:179)
     at buc.a(:com.google.android.gms:381)
     at jfo.run(:com.google.android.gms:1087)
     at itt.run(:com.google.android.gms:453)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     at iyg.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My Service class:, the print out in the try{} for the client is always : true, regardless if google play services crashes or not.

Client: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqd@3c738f4e Connected? :true

```
public class GoogleApiService  implements IGoogleApi{
private GoogleApiClient client;
private static final String TAG = "GoogleApiClient";

@Inject
public GoogleApiService(GoogleApiClient client){
    this.client = client;

}


public Observable<UserCurrentInfo> getLocationWeather(){
    Observable<WeatherResult> weatherObservable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {

        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"Trying to get some Weather");
            Log.d(TAG,"Client: " + client.toString() + " Connected? :" + client.isConnected());


            Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(client)
                    .setResultCallback(weather -> {
                        if (!weather.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            subscriber.onError(new Throwable("could not get weather"));
                            Log.d(TAG," Error getting weather" + weather.getStatus().toString());

                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Getting dem weathers");
                            subscriber.onNext(weather);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    });
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            throw new SecurityException("No permission: " + e);

        }
    });



    Observable<LocationResult> locationObservable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        try {
            Awareness.SnapshotApi.getLocation(client)
                    .setResultCallback(retrievedLocation -> {
                        if (!retrievedLocation.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            subscriber.onError(new Throwable("Could not get location."));
                            Log.d(TAG," Error getting location");

                        } else {
                            subscriber.onNext(retrievedLocation);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    });
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            throw new SecurityException("No permission: " + e);

        }
    });

    return Observable.zip(weatherObservable, locationObservable,
            (weather, location) -> {
                return new UserCurrentInfo(weather.getWeather(),location.getLocation());
            });
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class FavouritesPresenter implements BasePresenter<IFavouriteView>{

private IFavouriteView favView;
private String TAG = "FavPresenter";
private Subscription subscription;
private GetUserLocationWeatherUseCase useCase;

@Inject
FavouritesPresenter(GetUserLocationWeatherUseCase wlUseCase){
    this.useCase = wlUseCase;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    if(subscription != null){
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
public void getUserLocAndWeather(){
    subscription = useCase.execute().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(info -> {
                        favView.showText(
                                formatStringDecimals(info.getWeather().getTemperature(Weather.CELSIUS)+"",2),
                                info.getWeather().getConditions()[0],
                                formatStringDecimals(""+info.getLocation().getLatitude(),3),
                                formatStringDecimals("" + info.getLocation().getLongitude(),3)

                        );},
                    err ->{favView.showText("??",0,"","");}
            );
}
```

Usecase:

```
public class GetUserLocationWeatherUseCase implements Usecase<UserCurrentInfo> {
IGoogleApi apihelper;

public GetUserLocationWeatherUseCase(IGoogleApi helper){
    this.apihelper  = helper;
}
@Override
public Observable<UserCurrentInfo> execute(){
    return apihelper.getLocationWeather();

}
```

Usage in mainactivity:

```
@Inject
FavouritesPresenter favouritesPresenter;
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks;
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener connectionFailedListener;
@Inject
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    initInjector();
    favouritesPresenter.attachView(this);
    favouritesPresenter.onCreate();
    registerReceiverGPS();
}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null){
        registerCallbacks(this.mGoogleApiClient);
        registerFailedToConnect(this.mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    favouritesPresenter.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this.connectionCallbacks);
        mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(this.connectionFailedListener);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void registerCallbacks(GoogleApiClient client){
    this.connectionCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
            favouritesPresenter.getUserLocAndWeather(); //Call to presenter that initiates the observable chain, actually this              comes later after some GPS checks and such, but for easier cohesion
        }
        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}
    };
    client.registerConnectionCallbacks(this.connectionCallbacks);
}
```

Comment: what if you add this on your onCreate()
    if (GoogleApiClient== null) {

            GoogleApiClient= new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

        }

Comment: @Tony That already happens in the injector, the object itself is never actually null from what I could see, it always has the same reference in MainActivity and GoogleApiService

Comment: when exactly the programm crashes?at which function?

Comment: @Tony The program itself never crashes, only Google Play Services as provided in the stacktrace, that's why I'm having so much trouble fixing it.
However the crash most likely occurs on its way to fetch the data from the GoogleApiService.

It's quite random in its pattern as well, sometimes play services crashes at app start, but most often after being in the background. Sometimes it doesn't crash at the first time after being in background, which makes it so hard to locate.

Comment: have never worked with injection so i can't help you any further, have you tried it without the injection ?

Comment: Working on trying that right now, but I don't think the dependency injection is my problem

Comment: Updated with the usage code again. It seems that somewhere along the activity->presenter->usecase->service and back Google Play Services Crashes with the stacktrace provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your onStart() method only connect the googleApiClient's object and the rest things implement in onCreate() method .

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd go for is [move](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) the part in onStart() to onResume(), to make sure they are there when the user needs them, as that is the last method called before the App is shown. Same thing with onStop() to onPause(). But somehow that would seem like a too simple an answer.

Comment: Yeah it was in onResume() to begin with before I started moving it around to see why it behaved like that, however I'll just try to bind the call to a button instead of running it in onResume() to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Binding the call--asyncronously--to a button is _always_ a good idea IMO; if that becomes yr solution, buddhabath, consider dropping the other thread on viewDetach. Good on you for using DI; love it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(client)` is probably where your code begins the call to `com.google.android.gms:73`, so adding the NPE to your catch statement actually might be worth, particularly as it's intermittent.

& now a Note to others: I *only* suggest this because I see that they're using rxJava with some skill; look at the terseness of the two monad declarations in their `GoogleApiClient`! All they need to do is a `retryWhen(Func2<Integer, Throwable, Boolean>)` and evaluate the predicate in said functional parameter to be true given `throwable instanceof NPE` and count of 1, maybe 2. Before the zip, I think logging and releasing further NPEs--making further anomalous behavior apparent--might satisfy the firm, educated voices telling us never, ever to catch an NPE. ...or, if tweaking the noses of those firm, educated voices sounds like a good time, they could filter out further Exceptions by type while providing appropriate downstream [*reactions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction) to this predictable event...

[image: hmmmmm Kermit Sipping Tea]

I was about to say that you can do that because there isn't a bunch of code hanging around in the monad `create()` methods wishing it could be part of a side effect; however @buddhabath, I notice those `create()`s can generate exactly the subscription side effect you are describing--right on the subscription thread, actually:

You "should be" [catching *whatever* comes out of those `try`s](https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2016/02/21/rxjava-part-2-creating-an-observable/) and sending it down the rxChooChoo; the extant `onError` shouldn't be a problem b/c only one will be called per evaluation.
Just point the parameter of the catch at subscriber.onError() and any Throwable-[excepting these Exceptions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/exceptions/Exceptions.java#L76)-will be kept within the tracks, perhaps like the tracks I described above the Kermit, but that leaking `create()` is your bug.

tl;dr: Manually defining monads with `create()` deserves one's full attention; it's the real world, very "imperative"; literally anything could happen in there. Myself, I just now had the pleasure of discovering the new fromEmitter and also am glad to see [Observable.Generate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212014(v=vs.103).aspx) on the menu for rxJava 2.0.